# How to see Gatling html report in Azure DevOps and compare results

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gatling

I have a simple pipeline, in which gatling load script executes:
[My pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhCzp.jpg)

After the script is completed, we see the script execution time:
[Execution time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do86r.jpg)

My first question is: how can I extract value of execution time and compare it with previous execution (my script executes every night), and if execution time in last time is more than in previous time, I want to get notification.

Also, after execution generates report: [Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crJhz.jpg)

And my next question is: how can I open the generated report directly in Azure (or at least send it by mail as an attachment to a standard notification from Azure)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but FrontLine, our official enterprise product for Gatling, will be available on the Azure MarketPlace in a few weeks. Might be worth considering instead of tinkering your own thing.

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane LANDELLE, for your comment! About FrontLine,- will it be a free version?

Comment: The free version of FrontLine is Gatling.

Comment: Is the name FrontLine no longer used? Now it is simply call Gatling Enterprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Build timeline API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the execution time of a specific task.

I add a few more lines of scripts to my previous answer. Please check below scripts.

I added script `$result.records | where {$_.name -eq "MyTaskName"}`   to filter the task records by its name. Note: You need to define a unique **Display name** for your powershell task.

[image]

```
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=5.1"
echo $url

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

# filter the task's records by name
$taskResult = $result.records | where {$_.name -eq "MyTaskName"}  

# calculate the totaltime of the newest build
$time = [datetime]$taskResult.finishTime - [datetime]$taskResult.startTime

$thisTaskTime= $time.TotalMinutes

# get the last build's Id
$lasturl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId)&resultFilter=succeeded&`$top=2&api-version=5.1"

$buildResult =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $lasturl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

#extract last buildId
$lastBuildId = $buildResult.value[1].id

#get the timeline of the last build
$timeUrl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$($lastBuildId)/timeline?api-version=5.1"

$lastResult =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $timeUrl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

#Caculate the totaltime of the last build task
# filter the task's records by name
$lastTaskResult = $lastResult.records | where {$_.name -eq "TaskName"}  

$LastTime = [datetime]$lastTaskResult.finishTime - [datetime]$lastTaskResult.startTime

$lastTaskTime= $LastTime.TotalMinutes

#Store the result to varialbe  isLonger    
if($thisTaskTime -ge $lastTaskTime){ echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isLonger]True" }
```

If you want to use the azure default notification when the task execution time is greater then previous time. You can add another script task to the end of your pipeline to purposely fail your pipeline, if the time is greater. And then [set up a build fails notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#view-your-personal-notifications) for your project.

```
if($(isLonger) -eq "True")
{
    exit 1
}
```

- For your second question, I am afraid you cannot view the report directly in azure devops.

You can use [copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy out the generated report and use [publish build artifacts task](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390) to upload the report to azure devops server, where you can download directly from your build history.

**Copy Files task**

[image]

**Publish build artifact task**

[image]

Then you can download the report file from the build UI.

Go to **Builds** under **Pipelines**--> Select your pipeline--> Click lastest build from the **History**

[image]

There are other ways to upload the report file to the build besides Publish build artifact task by using statement `##vso[task.addattachment]value`, `##vso[task.uploadfile]local file path`. For example run below statement in a script task to add the report file to the build.

```
##vso[task.addattachment type=myattachmenttype;name=myattachmentname;]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\reportTempFolder\index.html
```

Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addattachment-attach-a-file-to-the-build) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, Levi Lu-MSFT! Your advice is very helpful!

Comment: Levi Lu-MSFT, could you explain: does the script for measuring time work correctly if the task is launched once a day? Today during execution of task i get this error: Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".    At D:\a\_temp\4c4045cc-fd90-4831-a27f-5452568bcd35.ps1:31 char:1.   + $LastTime = [datetime]$lastTaskResult.finishTime - [datetime]$lastTas ...    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException.
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : nullToObjectInvalidCast

Comment: It doesnot matter how many times the task runs in a day. From the error it seems it got the wrong `lastBuildId`.  Is above script task in your original pipeline or in the triggerring pipeline as i mentioned in my previous answer?  If it is in the original pipeline, try changing the parameter `definitions=$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId)` in for  $lasturl to `$(System.DefinitionId)`